# Parquet predicate pushdown filtering with Dask

Tags: dask, parquet

How can you apply predicate pushdown filters based on the Parquet min/max values when reading a Dask DataFrame?

Suppose you have a data lake with 4 Parquet files, each with `nickname` and `age` columns.  This table shows the Parquet filename, the age min value, and the age max value for each file.

```
| File          | min | max |
|---------------|-----|-----|
| pets1.parquet | 1   | 9   |
| pets2.parquet | 3   | 9   |
| pets3.parquet | 2   | 4   |
| pets4.parquet | 7   | 12  |
```

Suppose you'd like to perform an analysis on all the rows of data where the age is greater than 10.  You know that you can skip `pets1.parquet`, `pets2.parquet`, and `pets3.parquet` when performing this analysis because the max age in those files is less than the min value in our filter query.  Skipping files can make some analyses run a lot faster.

Here's the `read_parquet` method signature in the API docs: `dask.dataframe.read_parquet(path, columns=None, filters=None, categories=None, index=None, storage_options=None, engine='auto', gather_statistics=None, split_row_groups=None, chunksize=None, **kwargs)`.

Will the `filter` parameter help?  Can you please provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the filters argument is exactly what you want, something like the following:

dask.dataframe.read_parquet(path, filters=[('age', ">", 10)], ...)

This will skip row-groups/files where *none* of the rows can satisfy the condition.

Note that to get this to work, you may need either `gather_statistics=True` or a global `_metadata` file (whose existence will depend on how the data were written).